# How to use orElse when you need to invoke a method on the result?

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I have the following code blow. I tried finding a way to avoid the `if (something.isPresent())` row and declaring the `Optional<Something> something` as well. Instead I'd like to chain the `Optional.orElse()` method and return the result directly. But I can't seem to find a way, since the method needs to return null in case the element wasn't found, and if it was found, it needs to call a method on it before returning.

Is there a better way to do it?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class OrElseWhat {

    private class Something {
        private String it;
        Something(String it) { this.it = it; }
        String getIt() { return it; }
    }

    private List<Something> somethings = new ArrayList<Something>() {
        {
            add(new Something("one"));
            add(new Something("two"));
            add(new Something("three"));
        }
    };

    public String getFourOrNull() {
        Optional<Something> something = somethings.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.getIt().equals("four"))
                .findAny();

        if (something.isPresent()) {
            return something.get().getIt();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may call the method while your value is still in `Optional` form using `map`:

```
public String getFourOrNull() {
    return somethings.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getIt().equals("four"))
            .findAny()
            .map(Something::getIt)
            .orElse(null);
}
```

From `maps`'s [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

> If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and if the result is non-null, return an Optional describing the result. Otherwise return an empty Optional.

That said, if you can, listen to @Aaron and drop the `orElse` so that `getFourOrNull` returns the `Optional`. No method should ever return `null` in a code base where `Optional` is used.

Comment: Great! I thought map was going to get a NPE but I guess they thought about that as well :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should rather change the signature of your method to `Optional<String>` and always return `something`.

`Optional` were made for this kind of case : they make it possible to avoid returning some non-specific value (maybe it's `null` ? or `""` ? or `-1`) and rather plainly describe starting from your signature that maybe you'll be able to return some type, but not always.

Comment: I know. Unfortunately I can't return an optional in this case. Whoever is using it requires the null.